# Swift Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I have looked everywhere and can't find a reason why this code isn't working. I am trying to initialize my User class which will work with Firebase so I need to initialize a dictionary to be able to retrieve the JSON data. I've done this a bunch of times and haven't had any issues but for some reason this time xcode is giving me the "Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties". From what I can see all my properties are initialized. Am I missing something? Thank you in advance for your hep!

```
    enum UserAccessLevel: String {
    case unknown = "Unknown"
    case executiveProducer = "Executive Producer"
    case topTierProducer = "Top Tier Producer"
    case lowTierProducer = "Low Tier Producer"
    case crew = "Crew Member"
    case vendor = "Vendor"
    case talent = "Talent"
}

enum Access: String {
    case granted = "true"
    case denied = "false"
}

enum FIRUserData: String {
    case firstName = "firstName"
    case lastName = "lastName"
    case city = "city"
    case state = "state"
    case profileImage = "profileImage"
    case userName = "userName"
    case accessLevel = "accessLevel"
}

protocol User {
    var firstName: String { get set }
    var lastName: String { get set }
    var city: String { get set }
    var state: USAState { get set }
    var profileImage: String { get set }
    var userName: String { get set }
    var accessLevel: UserAccessLevel { get set }

    func createUser() throws
    func signInUser() throws
    func signOutUser()
    func archiveProject()
    func activateProject()
    func deleteProject()
}

class UserType: User {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var city: String
    var state: USAState
    var profileImage: String
    var userName: String
    var accessLevel: UserAccessLevel

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String, city: String, state: USAState, profileImage: String, u accessLevel: UserAccessLevel) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.profileImage = profileImage
        self.userName = "\(firstName).\(lastName)"
        self.accessLevel = accessLevel
    }

    init(userName: String, userData: Dictionary <String, Any>) {
        self.userName = userName

        if let firstName = userData[FIRUserData.firstName.rawValue] {
            self.firstName = firstName as! String
        }
        if let lastName = userData[FIRUserData.lastName.rawValue] {
           self.lastName = lastName as! String
        }
        if let city = userData[FIRUserData.city.rawValue] {
            self.city = city as! String
        }
        if let state = userData[FIRUserData.state.rawValue] {
            self.state = state as! USAState
        }
        if let profileImage = userData[FIRUserData.profileImage.rawValue] {
            self.profileImage = profileImage as! String
        }
        if let accessLevel = userData[FIRUserData.accessLevel.rawValue] {
            self.accessLevel = accessLevel as! UserAccessLevel
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second `init` for your `UserType` class, Xcode doesn't think that all of the class properties are guaranteed to be set, because `if` statements can fail.

The solution is to include an `else` block for all of your `if` statements:

```
init(userName: String, userData: Dictionary <String, Any>) {
    self.userName = userName

    if let firstName = userData[FIRUserData.firstName.rawValue] as? String {
        self.firstName = firstName
    } else {
        firstName = //something else
    }

    //do the same thing with other if statements
}
```

Comment: the user it is already using if let why not conditional cast it to String there also?  `if let firstName = userData[FIRUserData.firstName.rawValue] as? String {`

Comment: Better approach would be to use the nil coalescing operator `??` to assign a default value `firstName = userData[FIRUserData.firstName.rawValue] as? String ?? "default value"` or make the firstName property optional string `String?`

Comment: @LeoDabus Lol, sorry, once again I copied the code from OP. Good point with the `??` operator, too.

Comment: Thank you all! that was exactly it... When I did it previously they were forced unwrapped which I don't want to do anymore but that is why there was no error before.

Comment: No problem. Glad we all could help :)

Answer (score 0):

The second initializer doesn't initialize the fields if there is a value missing from the `userData` dictionary.  You need to decide what's going to happen to UserType's fields in that case.